# React facebook login do not open any popup or redirect in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-hooks, next.js

I am try to integrate my `react-facebook-login` into `nextjs, typescript` project. But in this project it can't open any thing like redirect or popup for login access. Where is the problem actually I can't understand. I am finding any solutions, blog or video. Please help me by giving the possible problem occurred and suggest how can I solve that problem.

Here is my Code example-

```
import FacebookLogin, { RenderProps } from "react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props";

const responseFacebook = (response: any) => {
    console.log(response)
}

<FacebookLogin
    appId = "265554609068125"
    autoLoad = {false}
    fields = "name,email,picture"
    callback = {responseFacebook}
    render = {(renderProps: RenderProps) => (
       <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} >
          Hello
       </button>
    )}
/>
```

You can checkout this url for getting problem in live demo - https://www.nekmart.com/users/login

In `console` I find this line-

`FB.login() called before FB.init().`

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the Facebook SDK is not loaded and initialized yet. Try setting `autoload` to `true`:

```
<FacebookLogin
    appId = "265554609068125"
    autoLoad = {true}
    fields = "name,email,picture"
    callback = {responseFacebook}
    render = {(renderProps: RenderProps) => (
       <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} >
          Hello
       </button>
    )}
/>
```

Be aware that the package did not get any update in the last 4 years, so it might be outdated.